# Modifying React-Native SectionList data

Tags: react-native, state, react-native-fs

**Edit**: I managed to delay the inital loading with the code below so it's now correctly reads and shows the file names on start. Now my only problem is updating the sectionlist immediately when some data changes.

```
componentWillMount() {
 setTimeout(() => {
  this.sortAndPlace(this.state.list, this.state.songs)
 })
}
```

I am trying to build an app and i am new to react-native and all it's libraries. I want to read files with react-native-fs, build a sectionlist data from there, and when the files are added, deleted and modified, i want to reflect that change with a state update.

```
RNFS.readDir(path)
.then((result) => {
 // log the file contents
 return Promise.all(result)
 })
 .then((contents) => {
 for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
 if (contents[i].isFile() && contents[i].name !== "ReactNativeDevBundle.js") 
{
  var labelTemp = contents[i].name.split(".")
  var label = labelTemp[0]
  song.push(new Song(label))
}
/*RNFS.unlink(contents[i].path)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('FILE DELETED');
  })
  // `unlink` will throw an error, if the item to unlink does not exist
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
});*/
}
})

sortAndPlace(secArray ,array) {
sectionNames = []
filteredSectionNames = []
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  sectionNames.push(array[i].name.substring(1,0))
}
filteredSectionNames = sectionNames.filter(function(item, pos) {
  return sectionNames.indexOf(item) == pos;
}).sort()
for (var i = 0; i < filteredSectionNames.length; i++) {
  secArray[i] = {id: i, title: filteredSectionNames[i], data: []}
}
for (var i = 0; i < secArray.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    if (array[j].name.substring(1,0) === secArray[i].title) {
      secArray[i].data[secArray[i].data.length] = {id: j, text: 
array[j].name}
    }
  }
}
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.text < b.text)
    return -1;
  if (a.text > b.text)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
for (var k = 0; k < secArray.length; k++) {
  secArray[k].data.sort(compare);
}
this.setState({
  list: secArray,
  songs: array
})
}
```

I am using my phone for testing with the command "react-native run-android". Promises are late to compose song array so sometimes app opens with the data, sometimes i have to re-enter to see the data. When i modify the files and re-create the array, i have to close the app completely and start it up to see the changes. Does redux solve this? Can you advice me on how to solve this? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this post due to i found my careless mistake. It turned out i didn't bind the functions properly. Now it's functional. Sorry for your time.